# Modify human_time_diff() to shorten "days" to "d" and "hours" to "h" etc

Tags: timestamp

I'm using the function echo time_ago() that displays the time like this:

**5 days ago** what's the best way to change it to **5d ago** ?

My research led me to human_time_diff() function located in "formatting.php" So I have tried directly editing the function located at /wp-includes/formatting.php but when I change **"hours"** to **"h"** and so on... it goes crazy and gives me errors. I know modifying the core isn't the best way, so any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no filter for output of that function. You can fork (copy/rename/edit) it or add wrapper that will replace strings in output like this:

```
function short_time_diff( $from, $to = '' ) {

    $diff = human_time_diff($from,$to);

    $replace = array(
        'hour'  => 'h',
        'hours' => 'h',
        'day'   => 'd',
        'days'  => 'd',
    );

    return strtr($diff,$replace);
}
```

PS afterthought - actually strings are localized so there is translation filter to use... But stuff to replace is to generic and that will risk breaking it elsewhere.

**UPDATE**

Since WP 4.0 there is a filter available for `human_time_diff`:

```
add_filter( 'human_time_diff', function($since, $diff, $from, $to) {

    $replace = array(
        'hour'  => 'h',
        'hours' => 'h',
        'day'   => 'd',
        'days'  => 'd',
    );

    return strtr($since, $replace);

}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: This strikes me as an exceedingly messy solution. Particularly, since it won't continue to work if the site has been translated. I would strongly reccomend creating a copy of <code>human_time_diff()</code> and then modifying the string literals, rather than a mickey moused string replacement solution.

Comment: @WhIteSidE I had covered fork as first option in my answer.

Comment: @whiteside - not sure there's any need to refer to a working solution as "mickey moused", particularly since the term is "mickey mouse'. Why not submit your solution as an answer and let the votes decide?!

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted the solution. I just simply copy/renamed/edited the function in my themes functions.php and it works great!@WhIteSidE Thanks for the input, perhaps you could have provided the answer you felt works better.